# In Android, what function will be called when my application is killed by other app

Tags: android

I want to do something when my application destory.But now, user may be use some other app to kill my app, at that time, i dont know what function will be called.I read the document and try a lot...but the onTerminate() can't do on android decive.

so how can i detect my application is killed? there are some functions will be called when app be killed? or some BroadcastReceiver will be send?

Comment: What do you want to do when the app is destroyed?

Comment: my app is downloading something, i want to save the progress into Sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the app is destroyed, the Android system **might** call `onDestroy()`. However, this is not guaranteed. For example, if the user uses the standard App Management utility to "Force Close" your app, `onDestroy()` will not be called.

If you want to save the state of your app, you need to do so during normal operation. If you need to store data temporarily, you can override `onSaveInstanceState()`. If you need to store data more permanently, you can use either `SharedPreferences`, a SQLite database, or a file. See the Android Developer docs for more details.

I also suggest that you read the Android Developer docs about the Activity life cycle.

Comment: my app is downloading something,if the user uses the standard App Management utility to "Force Close" my app, i don't know how to save the progress...

Comment: @Evlix I don't think you will have an opportunity to do so. "Force Close" circumvents the regular life cycle events. This is why you need to save progress periodically during the normal execution of your download code.

Comment: eh..i also do that during the normal execution of my download code.but now, some user maybe "Force Close" when my app is downloading.

Comment: @Evlix There's not much you can do about that. You will most likely have to repeat some of your download since the most recent save. Hopefully you save enough state to easily resume from that point. Also, you need to balance the time between saves between the amount of work you might have to repeat and the overhead of writing to disk.

Comment: I once saved state every second, but this operation too frequent..so i want to save when "Force Close".

Comment: @Evlix As far as I know, there is no way to do this. Your app will **not** be notified when it is force closed. Since you determined that saving every second is too frequent, increase the amount of time between saves. Try every 10, 20, 30, or more seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do runs opposite of why someone would be killing an app. 
When the user is trying to purposely close the app, that user does NOT want the app to do anything more.

Why do you need to check if the user is killing the app? If you need to save data, then you should design your app to save data when the user is actively using your app.

Comment: my app is downloading something, when other app to kill my app, i want to save the progress.

Comment: @Evlix I assume you are downloading in an AsyncTask or some other multi-threaded class, right? If not you should be. If you are, then you should periodically save the progress as part of the normal execution of this thread. Then you don't have to worry about the app being killed. You will only loose the progress since the most recent save.

Comment: I once saved state every second, but this operation too frequent..so i want to save when "Force Close".